# Is the any mistakein the code

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

This code takes time and haven't finished yet on Mathematica 12.1, Is there any mistake?

```
Assuming[-1 < v1 < 1 && -1 < v2 < 1 && m1 > 0 && m2 > 0, 
 Solve[m1*v1*(1/Sqrt [1 - v1^2]) + m2*v2*(1/Sqrt [1 - v2^2]) == 
    m1*u1*(1/Sqrt [1 - u1^2]) + m2*u2*(1/Sqrt [1 - u2^2]) && 
   m1*(1/Sqrt [1 - v1^2]) + m2*(1/Sqrt [1 - v2^2]) == 
    m1*(1/Sqrt [1 - u1^2]) + m2*(1/Sqrt [1 - u2^2]), {u1, u2}]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Try: `Solve[A == (m1 u1)/Sqrt[1 - u1^2] + (m2 u2)/Sqrt[1 - u2^2] && B == m1/Sqrt[1 - u1^2] + m2/Sqrt[1 - u2^2], {u1, u2}] /. A -> (m1 v1)/Sqrt[1 - v1^2] + (m2 v2)/Sqrt[1 - v2^2] /. B -> m1/Sqrt[1 - v1^2] + m2/Sqrt[1 - v2^2]`.

Comment: Thanks @MariuszIwaniuk but I don't understand the sterminology of the solution like 
... 1... + ... 1 ... + 2m1^2 (... 1 ...)^2, what does this mean ... "a number" ... ?

Comment: Try `InputForm[Solve[A==...]]`